# How to use Count without Group By?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this. The last digit in the 'Subject' column indicates the Semester.

| Roll | Subject |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MTMG1 |
| 2 | MTMG3 |
| 2 | CEMG3 |
| 3 | MTMG1 |
| 3 | CEMG3 |
| 4 | PHSG3 |
| 5 | MTMG3 |
| 5 | CEMG3 |

From the above table, I want a table like this

| Roll | Subject |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | CEMG3 |
| 5 | CEMG3 |

The logic is that: I want to find the list of candidates who will appear in 'CEMG3' with a condition. The condition is that the candidate must have to appear in at least two subjects for the same semester.  So Roll no 3 will not be included in the table as though the candidate is appearing in 'CEMG3', but he/she is not appearing in any other subjects in the 3rd semester.

I have tried the following query. But it can not give me the desired result as `Group by` removes few rows containing 'CEMG3'. Again without `Group By`, counting is becoming difficult for me.

```
     $ss1a=mysqli_query($con, "select RollNo, Subject from 
     (select RollNo, count(RollNo), Subject FROM table where mid(Subject, 5,1)='3'  
     group by RollNo having count(RollNo)>1)  where  Subject='CEMG3' ");
```

Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: You can't have two `WHERE` clauses. Combine them with `AND`.

Comment: Use `RIGHT(Subject, 1)` to get the last character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with a subquery that finds the candidates who are in at least two subjects in the 3rd semester.

```
SELECT t1.Roll, t1.Subject
FROM table AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT Roll
    FROM table
    WHERE RIGHT(Subject, 1) = '3'
    GROUP BY Roll
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t2 ON t1.Roll = t2.Roll
WHERE t1.Subject = 'CEMG3'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
select r.* from registar r where r.subject = "CEMG3" where (select count(*) from registrar r1 where r1.roll = r.roll and right(subject, 1) = '3') > 1;
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77ef65f7296375d85c1cf9127d37e79a).